# ASP.net MVC passing data from Partial View Back To the Main

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am dynamically loading my Partial View using Ajax, so that the textboxes for entry are on the same page as my main data list, without having to reload the main data list each time an edit is made. Initially the data list is shown, the user can click on an entry to load it into the textbox, currently in view only mode, after this they can select edit to edit the entry.  The issue I have is the Edit button is in my main view, and the id of the item I want to edit is in the Partial View.

My Main View

```
@model PresentationLayer.Models.HR.EquipmentTypes
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Equipment";
}
@section script{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        }); 

</script>
}
<h2>Links</h2>
<h3>All links</h3>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var equipmentType in Model.EquipmentType)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Ajax.ActionLink(equipmentType.Name, "Index", "Link", new { id = equipmentType.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "linkEdit", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })</td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>

@Html.Partial("LinkEdit", Model.TypeToEdit)

@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Link", new { id = equipmentType.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "linkEdit", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
```

My Partial View

```
@using PresentationLayer.Models.HR
@model PresentationLayer.Models.HR.EquipmentType

<div id="linkEdit">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit</legend>
            @if (Model.isLocked == true)
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new {id="hiddenid"})
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })

            }
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

I need to be able to get the hiddenfor data out and able to push the id in at the equipmentType.Id part of my Ajax Edit call,  I originally was trying to use TempData as this did what I was after, but I didn't initally understand how temporary TempData was.  As Originally the requirement was that the edit buttons were in the Main layout, but that seemed impossible to do.

I am fairly new to ASP.net MVC, been coding ASP.net for a few years and works on MVC within Java, but this has left me at a bit of a stop.  Hope I have given enough information, if not let me know and I will try to expand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Edit button is outside of the foreach loop. It won't get any id at all.

Place the Edit button within the loop to get the value of equipmentType.Id. So each row will have it's own Edit button. That's the normal thing to do in a tabular data with edit function.

Comment: I understand that is the way it works, but it is a requirement that there is only one edit button, that services all items, and it would work if I placed it in the Partial View, but then I wouldn't be able to get the required styling that places the buttons at the top of the page.  I know I am sounding like a pain, but these are the parameters I have to work with, thanks for the quick response though.

Comment: You can place a checkbox beside the item and fetch the id onchecked via javascript. You can get the edit data via ajax also when the checkbox is checked. Place your javascript function in the main page which can access controls in the partial page. Show an alert if no checkbox is selected. Hope that helps.